# Object parameter vanishes in MySQL DAO java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created an object *member* with parameters:

> firstName, lastName, memberID, personal number and nBoats.

Constructing the object and setting values for the parameters works fine, debug shows that they are set, however when sending the object to the SQLDAO, the `memberID` is somehow missing and set to null. Thus the object cant be saved and gives the error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Column memID cannot be null
```

The code that we are using to save new Member in the sql database is 
 `SQLDAO.saveMember(newMember);` and that is in the memberdatahandling class.

In the DAO class we wrote this:

```
 public static void saveMember(Member member) {

    String query2 = "INSERT into member(firstName, lastName, memID, pnr, nBoats)"
            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


    try {
        Connection conn = openConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2);

        preparedStmt.setString(1, member.getMemberFirstName());
        preparedStmt.setString(2, member.getMemberLastName());
        preparedStmt.setString(3, member.getMemberID());
        preparedStmt.setString(4, member.getMemberPersonalNumber());
        preparedStmt.setInt(5, member.getMemberNBoats());

        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        preparedStmt.close();

        conn.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException| SQLException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't save Member because of a database connection error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a `System.out.println(member.getMemberID())` before setting it in the prepared statement to make sure it's returning a non-null value.  Also, double-check the code for `getMemberID()` to make sure it is correct, too.  Finally, closing your Connection should be done in a `finally` block (or use Java 7's try-with-resources) otherwise it doesn't get closed when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Objects in java do not have parameters, they have members, a.k.a. fields.  And each and every field has a type.  So, telling us the field names without telling us the field types is not very cool.  Also, spaces are not allowed in identifiers in java, and one of the ***foremost*** habits that a programmer must have is accuracy.  Finally, your `member.getMemberID()` must be returning null, so the member object already contains a null memberId by the time this function is executed, so the code you are showing us is probably irrelevant to your problem.